# Sequence of random variables, convergence in distribution

Tags: probability, limits

**Exercise** Let $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ a sequence of random variables such that $$p_{X_n}(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{n} & \forall  x=0,\frac{1}{n},\ldots,\frac{n-1}{n}\\ 0 & \text{if not}\end{cases}$$

Calculate the limit of the cumulative distribution function of $X_n$.

This is what I did:

For each $n$, we have $$F_{X_n}(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & x<0\\ \frac{k+1}{n} & \text{if } \frac{k}{n} \leq x < \frac{k+1}{n},\quad k=0,\ldots,n-1 \\ 1 & \text{if } x >\frac{n-1}{n} \end{cases}$$

For $x<0$, $F_{X_n}(x)=0$ for all $n$, so $\lim F_{X_n}(x)=0$, I am not sure what is the limit for other values of $x$, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is meant by "$1$ if not"?

Comment: I meant $0$, not $1$

Comment: Another thing: describing $F$ you probably meant $1$ if $x\geq\frac{n-1}{n}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that for $x\in\left(0,\frac{n-1}{n}\right)$ you actually found that: $$F_{X_n}\left(x\right)-\frac{1}{n}\leq x<F_{X_n}\left(x\right)$$
or equivalently: $$x<F_{X_n}\left(x\right)\leq x+\frac{1}{n}$$

What will happen if $n\to\infty$?